# Is ‘Wasawaththi Mara’ a demon or some type of god?

Tags: god, mara

Mara is not considered a positive entity in Buddhism. Is ‘Wasawaththi Mara’ a god or a demon? I heard he is one of the powerful gods. Is that true?

Comment: The word "Wasawaththi" appears almost nowhere on the internet. I guess it's a non-standard or phonetic transliteration to the Latin alphabet.

Comment: In Sri Lanka, Wasawaththi Mara is used for Mara sometimes. And considered as king of hell and, a being powerful to some degree. Even some gods(not very powerful gods) are afraid of him.